# Como adicionar arquivos que foram incluídos ao projeto via upload ao repositório git?

Tags: git

Tenho um sistema onde é possível adicionar extensões e plugins via interface web através do upload de um arquivo `.zip`.

Esse arquivo `.zip` é descompactado pelo sistema e os arquivos vão para uma pasta específica do servidor.

Porém, esses arquivos acabam não sendo incluídos ao repositório do projeto (privado), que sempre fica desatualizado. Se eu precisar editar algum desses novos arquivos, acabo tendo que baixá-los do servidor.

Gostaria de saber como posso incluir esses novos arquivos ao repositório após o upload, de forma a tê-los localmente ao rodar o `git pull`, por exemplo.

Comment: O que exatamente você tem em mente? Você quer que seu servidor faça commit / push desses arquivos a cada upload? Quer que toda madrugada algo assim aconteça? Quer um procedimento manual para fazer commits com esse arquivo? No geral eu não sei até que ponto é interessante persistir configurações de ambiente (nesse caso, plugins e extensões) no repo do seu projeto... Se você realmente quer fazer isso, eu ao menos criaria um repositório separado para essas configurações de plugin e incluiria esse repo como submódulo no projeto principal.

Comment: Sugiro uma pesquisa pela API do GitHub: https://developer.github.com/v3/ - [Cria o arquivo no repositório e faz o upload](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/)
- Depois, [Faz o commit](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/)

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly, excelente observação! Realmente não faz muito sentido essa abordagem que eu queria realizar. Na verdade, eu não tinha nada em mente. O como-fazer seria minha principal dúvida, ou seja, acabei não levando em conta a automatização, ou não, do processo.

Answer (score 1):

A melhor forma de você fazer isso seria a utilização da [API do GitHub](https://developer.github.com/v3).

Você precisa:

- [Criar o arquivo no repositório](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#create-a-file);
- [Enviar o arquivo para o repositório](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#update-a-file);
- [Realizar o commit](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#get-a-single-commit).

Answer (score 0):

Você já verificou na raiz do projeto se tem algum arquivo chamado

".gitignore"

Este arquivo pode estar ignorando arquivos do tipo zip (*.zip) ou então a pasta onde o upload é feito!